# Vue: Dynamically access object by variable value

Tags: vue.js, object, variables, eval

My Vue component has a method `setQuestions(questionpack)`. As you can see, there is an argument called `questionpack`.

In my component and before export default {...} there are several imports like

```
<script>
   import Cars from "./../questionsCars.js";  // Content: var Cars = { questions: { ... } }
   import Bikes from "./../questionsBikes.js";
   import Trucks from "./../questionsTrucks.js";
   ...

   export default {
     ...
   }
</script>
```

This static code works well:

```
setQuestions() {
  this.questions = {
    ...Cars.questions,
    ...Cars.questionsAppendOnSingle,
  };
}
```

But if I try to access this Cars object by variable value like `setQuestions('Cars')`, it won't work:

```
setQuestions(questionpack) {
  console.log("QP: " + questionpack);  // Outputs 'Cars' as aspected
  this.questions = {
    ...eval(questionpack).questions,
    ...eval(questionpack).AppendOnSingle,
  };
}
```

It spits this error message:

> vendor.js:1108 [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "ReferenceError:
> Cars is not defined"

What's the trick here?

Comment: how do you call that method?

Comment: I call it by: `export default { created() { this.setQuestions(this.questionpack); } }`

Comment: how are you defining the `questionpack`?

Comment: It's a property: `<question-container :questionpack="'Cars'"></question-container>` and defined in like `props: { questionpack: { required: true, type: String, validator: function (value) { return ( ["Cars", "Bikes", "Trucks", "Multi"].indexOf(value) !== -1 );  }, }, },`